# Fast Pre-existing embeddable scripting language I can use in C#

Tags: c#, scripting

I am working on a "building game" (in the same vein as MineCraft, Roboblox and Dwarf Fortress). Obviously this game will be completely brimming with objects that interact with one another. I'd like to use a scripting language to describe the objects and their behaviours. Since these scripts will be executed in rapid succession, I need to find a scripting language such as lua, python, etc that is both very fast, and easily integrable into a C# program. Bonus points for specific information on how to implement.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481150/need-information-on-windows-scripting-and-supporting-scripting-in-my-c-applicati and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191222/what-is-a-good-embeddable-language-i-can-use-for-scripting-inside-my-software

Comment: I know of lua, I know of a lot of options. Only a fool relies on their own opinions to make an important decision. I'm appealing to the internet in hopes that someone can show me something specific that is a better approach, and it seems someone has (see the use C# as script post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use C# :P It's possible to compile and load .cs files at runtime.

And since C# is statically typed the scripts will be rather fast(just as fast as any other (non *ngen*-ed) C# code. And of course the compiler is already included with .net.

See [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx)

The main weakness of C# as scripting language is that it needs to compile a whole assembly at a time. So it's not well suited for an interactive command prompt.

Comment: Even if it is an option, you have to consider that usually script are changed *during* the program runtime, so ypou have to provide an insulated appdomain to unload the old compiled assembly and replece with a new one, or accept to load in memory multiple copies of the same compiled script.

Comment: Spawning a new appdomain with the correct security properties is probably a good idea with any scripting language. And since .net 4 code security is a lot easier to use than in earlier versions.

Comment: Okay this is very interesting. lets say this code is programmed to belong in a pre-existing namespace, and it references several things in this name space, would that compile and load into the architecture without a hitch, and would the other objects in the namespace have access to everything that was just compiled as if it were there all along? (assuming of course they'd have to sense the objects added through reflection or some registration process) Because if so, then you totally just answered my prayers.

Comment: It behaves just like adding a new class-library to your solution. You need to supply the appropriate assembly references so it can compile. Your existing assemblies won't have a reference to the new assembly, so they only can access the new objects using either known interfaces or reflection. Not sure why you are mentioning namespaces.

Comment: Er, sorry it's late here. What you are saying is practically what I wanted to hear. Thank you VERY much. If I had the reputation I'd up this answer, but sadly, all I can do is select it as my answer. Good night. :)

Comment: @Ben: I've done this with FSharpCodeProvider. It's simpler than one would think but it takes some setting up. If you compile the code as an Executable you can even run `Invoke` on the EntryPoint and it would behave like it's own program. If C# it would need to have a Main of course.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am building this project in xna, and intended to release it both on PC and XBox. The real strength of this approach is that I can include the uncompiled game object classes with the PC version and allow people to modify existing game objects with more interesting behaviours, and to even create their own new objects that extend the game. I could then use the code they submit to the community toward the XBox version as updates, as all content must be compiled at build time. The reason for this is that development for Xbox through XNA doesn't allow this AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

IronPython http://ironpython.codeplex.com/ is well mantained easy to interop with your application, and you can even compile it programmatically to be faster in your game.
A quick start example can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/C_Sharp_and_Iron_Python.aspx
once yoiu read you for sure get the idea on how to start.
Other thing, since IronPython is based on the DLR Dynamic Language Runtime MS library, it should be easy to change the engine without changing hyour main program infrastructure.
Just for completeness I will cite as well http://boo.codehaus.org/ boo. This language was for sure earlier than the other one, and there is a book about writing DSL's from it ( look over the net for DSL languages in boo I don't want advertise here ), whith I think you can grab from idea to make your game script looking better.

Answer (score 0):

IronPython and IronRuby stand out as obvious candidates since they are .net languages. The only downside is that they are no longer actively developer by Microsoft. That may not matter since they won't stop working, but they may not move on to new .net versions too rapidly.